# Removing space from a .csv with macOS

Tags: macos, csv, sed

Here is my CSV :

```
"de,aabauerschaft,Aabauerschaft,07,1,52.083333,7.383333"

"de,aach,Aach,01,1,47.85,8.85"
```

I tried this : sed 's/[[:blank:]]*//g' GermanCities_1.csv

expected this :

```
"de,aabauerschaft,Aabauerschaft,07,1,52.083333,7.383333"
"de,aach,Aach,01,1,47.85,8.85"
```

returns error : sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

If anyone could help i'd thank him so much !

Comment: First are you sure it's a good idea to unconditionally strip spaces?  What would my beloved *Bad Homburg* look like afterwards?

Comment: you can use `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' as written here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

Just look at this link : [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)